# Microsoft Project Online SDK API/REST API Support

Tags: java, rest, sdk, project-online

I want to create/update project in microsoft project online using some reference data. Is there REST API or SDK available? Especially for Java clients?

Answer (score 3):

Yes project online provides REST API

Few examples -

**1) Get All Projects information from Project Online**

```
http://<pwa_site>/_api/ProjectData/Projects
```

**2) Get Project GUID**

```
http://<pwa_site>/_api/ProjectData/Projects/?$select=ProjectId
```

**3) Get Specific Project information based on GUID**

```
http://<pwa_site>/_api/ProjectData/Projects(guid'<GUID here>')
```

**4) Get Assignment Information of a Project (Tasks Assigned)**

```
http://<pwa_site>/_api/ProjectData/Projects(guid'<GUID here>')/Assignments
```

**5) Get Assignments based on user**

```
http://<pwa_site>/_api/ProjectData/Projects(guid'<GUID here>')/Assignments?
$filter=ResourceName eq '<Name>'
```

**6) Get Tasks of a Project**

```
http://<pwa_site>/_api/ProjectData/Projects(guid'<GUID here>')/Tasks
```

Comment: Where did you find that information? Does MS have documentation on that??

Comment: No, MS does not have this documentation, in one of my project, my team needs to work on some feature which requires such APIS, then I found this information through a google search and it works well for our use case.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to import data dynamicly?

Comment: @Mikeez - Please elaborate your use case what do you mean by dynamically?.  You can certainly call these APIs to get the data for specific or all the projects and import/upload in required storage.

Comment: Per se, I would like to import all MS Project Online into MySQL directly and automatically.

Comment: There is no out of the box feature for that, You need to build. You can write a backgroup process/service which will run on a schedule basis, fetch the data using APIs and upload in the MySQL in the desired structure.

Comment: When you say fetch the data using APIs, you mean like a python script for example?

Comment: @Mikeez - Yes, in language python, Java , C# etc. which allow you to call rest api.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone runs across this...the documentation for the Microsoft Project Online OData API is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/project-odata/jj163015(v=office.15)

It is a bit lacking but covers the 6 examples given by Mukesh Arora.